# Transpose Matrix Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, pivot, transpose

I have the follow table with the columns names ID/PNO,STORE and PUSH available.

With the PUSH values for each row(in this case I just have a ID, but the table contains more), I would like to create the second table(yellow one in the picture).

Then the target is: create new columns for each STORE(listed 7 adh,ayc,maeg,rot,witz,mar,bud), where each store will receive the value from the PUSH column.

The result expected is the yellow table which I will add in the same dataframe used to generate the ID,STORE,PUSH tables.

I tried (1st idea):

```
 pushTrasnpose = combined_sf2[['PNO','store','Push']].transpose()
 pushTrasnpose.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

and(2nd idea):

```
pd.pivot(df, index='ID', columns='STORE', values='PUSH').loc[df.ID]
```

But this error appear as well for the 2nd idea:

```
    "error pivot_simple() got multiple values for argument 'index'"
```

Any of them are giving me what I`m expecting to have.

What I would like as a result is:
[image]

Any help would be very appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close with pivot but your syntax is a bit off.

This should work:

```py
df.pivot(index='ID', columns='STORE', values='PUSH')
```